# apache/mod_gnutls ssl certificate based authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, x509, gnutls

I'm using apache with gnutls. I've configured both to request authentication from the client.
When providing the certificate it works. But it works also if I provide another that the correct certificate. That means, if I use the one which is signed by the ca mentioned in site.ca.asc it works as expected. If I use another which is NOT signed by the mentioned ca, the access is also granted. Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks for your help

m.

```
GnuTLSEnable on
GnuTLSPriorities SECURE256:-CIPHER-ALL:+COMP-DEFLATE:-MAC-ALL:-MD5:-ANON-DH:-3DES-CBC:-CAMELLIA-256-CBC:-CAMELLIA-128-CBC:-AES-256-CBC:-AES-128-CBC:+VERS-TLS1.2:+VERS-TLS1.1:+SHA512:+SHA384:+SHA256:+SHA1:+VERS-TLS1.0:+ARCFOUR-128:+CAMELLIA-256-CBC:+AES-256-CBC

GnuTLSCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/webserver.cert
GnuTLSKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/webserver.key
GnuTLSExportCertificates on
GnuTLSClientVerify require
GnuTLSClientCAFile /etc/apache2/ssl/site.ca.asc
```